# Create synonym of variations tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-synonyms

When asking a question about the difference between the manga and anime, I would have never thought to use the variations tag.  Can we create a synonym of this tag as [anime-manga-difference](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-manga-difference), or at least [differences](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences)?

Comment: Can we just burninate the whole tag? Who would 'follow' or 'ignore' this tag? It seems like a clear meta-tag. Shouldn't this information be in the titles, rather than the tag? More [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/110/71), at the original meta discussion.

Comment: Marking as declined for lack of a better status because we did away with the variations tag long ago and so this request doesn't really make sense anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of [anime-manga-difference](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-manga-difference). Of the 9 questions tagged as this, 4 of them aren't about comparing anime and manga. It would quickly get out of hand if we had tags for every pair such as [light-novel-anime-difference](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel-anime-difference),[anime-movie-difference](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-movie-difference), [visual-novel-live-action-difference](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-novel-live-action-difference) (okay maybe the last one is unlikely, but you get the picture). Furthermore, it's not clear what should be done if there are 2 different versions of the anime. If I wanted to ask what the differences are between Eat-Man '97 and Eat-Man '98, would I use the tag [anime-anime-differences](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-anime-differences)? That's just silly.

I don't have a strong feeling one way for [differences](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences) vs. [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations), but it's not clear to me that the former is more intuitive than the latter. I'd be very surprised if new users use the correct tag regardless of which we choose. From a practical standpoint, I'm just slightly in favor of keeping the status-quo, simply because people are already using it and may not notice the switch.

Comment: Agree, except for 'people are already using it' -> 'A select group of private beta testers are using it' :) They can manage to deal with this!

Comment: @Veger That's why it's only a very slight difference. If we had already started public beta, I'd be quite a bit less willing to switch without a good argument.

Comment: I don't see `variations` being really clear, well actually it makes no sense to me. I would agree on `differences`, that does express "difference".

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the [anime-manga-difference](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-manga-difference) tag looks like should be the main one to me. [variations](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations) is quite unclear.

In any case, no-one can create synonyms yet, since according to the [Privileges page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), we need 1250 reputation.